# Update record using sequelize(mysql) + nodejs

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, sequelize.js

My table name: **TIME**

My table data fields:

start : 10.00am
stop: null

Now i want to update **null** as current date

```
exports.updateGroup = function (req, res) {
    Time.update(req.body, {
        stop: new Date(),
        where: {
            id: req.body.id
        }
    }).then(data => {
        return res.status(200).send(data);
    }).catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, err => {
        return res.status(422).send(err.errors[0].message);
    }).catch(err => {
        return res.status(400).send(err.message);
    });
};
```

Now its showing same as null after update

My req.body:  { mainId: 1, start: '', stop: '' }

```
my Time model :

 var Time = sequelize.define('time', {
             start: Sequelize.DATE,
             stop: Sequelize.DATE,

     });
```

Comment: What status does it return ? Show us your sequelize TIME model and your req.body key values.

Comment: my Time model: var Time = sequelize.define('time', {
         start: Sequelize.DATE,
         stop: Sequelize.DATE,


     });

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you pass wrong id since there is not a `req.body.id` property based on body format you've posted.

Secondly, the `update` method gets two arguments as referenced at [official sequelize documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-update).

This should work:

```
Time.update({
    start: req.body.start,
    stop: req.body.stop
}, {
    where: {
        id: req.body.mainId
    }
})
```